# Evento Droppable jQuery não funciona

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-n-drop

Possuo o seguinte código para efetuar o evento de Drag and Drop:

```
$(".device-profiles").draggable({
    revert : true,
    start: function(event, ui) {
        dragColor = $(this).attr("data-color");
        console.log("dragColor: " + $(this).attr("data-color"));
    } 
});

$(".mediaplayer-profiles").droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui){
        $(this).removeClass($(this).attr("data-color"));
        $(this).attr("data-color", ui.draggable.attr("data-color"));
        $(this).addClass($(this).attr("data-color"));
    }
});
```

Na primeira vez que executo o drop, o mesmo funciona, mas quando tento alterar para outros lugares o efeito já não funciona mais.

O que pode estar ocasionando essa falha?

Comment: Gumaro, testei seu código no JSFiddle, porém com uma versão antiga do jQuery e do jQuery UI. Não deu nenhum erro. Dê uma olhada no console do Browser e veja não tem nenhuma mensagem de erro. No caso, o uso da propriedade `revert` no `draggable` sempre vai bloquear o drop, fazendo que o elemento volte para a posição inicial do `draggable`. Se puder inclua um pouco da marcação para ajudar a contextualizar ou crie um [mcve](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) no [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: @Wakim teria como me mostrar essa versão do jsfiddle que você testou? aqui sempre ocorre o mesmo erro.

Comment: Usei esse arquivo (http://jsfiddle.net/Morals/YnWc2/8/) como base. Está com o código original, alterei para colocar o seu e funcionou.

Comment: @Wakim no meu caso eu preciso que ele retorne a posição atual. Também estou utilizando vários elementos draggable o qual farão a troca de cores, parecido com a sugestão do Jader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você esta usando o atributo `data` de forma errada, apesar de funcionar dessa forma, existe um método especifico [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) que é mais fácil e limpo de utilizar.

E para utilizar uma variável entre funções diferentes, você deve declara-la no escopo global primeiro.

Segue exemplo funcionando:

**jquery**

```
var dragColor; // declarar a variavel no escopo global

$(".device-profiles").each(function () {
    $(this).addClass($(this).data('color')); // *opcional* colocar o data-color como class em cada elemento
}).draggable({
    revert: true,
    start: function (event, ui) {
        dragColor = $(this).data('color');
        console.log("dragColor: " + dragColor);
    }
});

$(".mediaplayer-profiles").droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).removeClass($(this).data('color')).data('color', dragColor).addClass(dragColor);
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="draggable">
    <p class="device-profiles" data-color="teste1">Drag me to my target</p>
    <p class="device-profiles" data-color="teste2">Drag me to my target</p>
    <p class="device-profiles" data-color="teste3">Drag me to my target</p>
</div>
<div id="droppable" class="mediaplayer-profiles">
    <p>Drop here</p>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaderw/nx02dcen/)

Comment: Jader: A parte da coloração está sendo atribuída muito antes, com um append do jQuery. As cores são provenientes de um array e somente uma div pode conter uma única cor, fazendo a alteração entre elas.

Testei da forma que disponibilizou aqui e não obtive sucesso, teria alguma outra dica?

Obs.: Estou fazendo a manutenção dele para funcionar em Tablet, o anterior era feito em HTML5 mas não funciona no mesmo.

Comment: Realizando algumas revisões aqui percebi que a classe "ui-droppable" existente acaba se perdendo quando realizo o drop.